# How do you improve the speed of LoginAuthentication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm working on adding the LocalAuthentication framework to allow users to authenticate with a fingerprint on comparable devices. Everything works properly, but when a user is authenticated with their finger print it takes between 10-15 seconds for the proper segue to be performed, is this typical, or is there something wrong with the way I'm authenticating a user?
Code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; [self.view setBackgroundColor:[NPSColor NPSBackgroundColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Register" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onRegisterTapped)]; self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil; if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) { [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:@"Login?" reply:BOOL success, NSError *error {
                      if (error) {

                      }

                      if (success) {
                         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSeg" sender:self];

                      } else {

                      }

                  }];
} else {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                message:@"Your device cannot authenticate using TouchID."
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it may be that performing a segue has to do with a view action which should mainly be performed on the main thread. I'm not too sure but it could very well be the `evaluatePolicy` method is performed on a background thread. If this is the case, you would want to throw your `performSegue` on the main thread.

To do so, use this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSeg" sender:self];
});
```

Comment: Yep that was it! Thank you I didn't even consider that it maybe handling some multi threading for me.

Comment: Anytime! Glad to see it helped :)